# NeedDataSource and ItemDataBinding are firing only once

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik, reporting

I'm changing my report parameter through NeedDataSource or ItemDataBinding events but these events are firing only once? Why? It fires only when the report is generated the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report data is cached for optimization purposes. In most cases Bindings or and ObjectDataSource can replace the need of events.